# php unable to get serialized data in php

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

I am using jQuery to convert form data to serialized form using:

```
var data = $('#frm').serialize();
```

In php I get this:

`fiscalyear_id=4&category=Category+A&isgraph=on&Title=a&Value=a&Title=b&Value=b&category=Category+B&Title=c&Value=c&Title=d&Value=d&category=Category+C&Title=e&Value=e&Title=f&Value=f&data;=&csrf_check=9c288285b379701b27c3836091c00b04`

And when I do:

```
parse_str($_POST['data'], $data);
pretty_print($data);
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [fiscalyear_id] => 4
    [category] => Category C
    [isgraph] => on
    [Title] => f
    [Value] => f
    [data;] => 
    [csrf_check] => 9c288285b379701b27c3836091c00b04
)
```

As can be seen, not all paramters are coming in array above. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong ? Thanks for the help

Comment: Your values are being reasigned, so you only see the last one - Title=a...Title=b. Please show your form html

Comment: you have duplicated keys. Why you not using Value[] on client side?

Comment: `&Title=c&Value=c&Title=d` this is not the right way of sending data it should be `&Title[]=c&Value[]=c&Title[]=d` etc.. since it should be in array format else the POST or GET will only get the last value.

Comment: The values in the array are being overridden due to duplicate keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parse_str parses the string in variable and you are getting it into array.
but duplicate array keys are not possible,

hence you are not getting all the values because they have the same key!